# mongorestore fails on empty system.js.bson

Tags: mongodb, dump, mongorestore

I’m trying to restore dumped db to the local server but it fails.

To make dump I run:
`mongodump --host somehost.com -d app123 --port 10043 --username my_username --password my_password --out /tmp/mongodump`
and it works fine.

To restore I run:
`mongorestore --db my_db --drop /tmp/mongodump/app123`
and it fails on empty file:

```
2015-01-05T12:56:47.759+0100 /tmp/mongodump/app123/system.js.bson
2015-01-05T12:56:47.759+0100    going into namespace [my_db.system.js]
file /tmp/mongodump/app123/system.js.bson empty, skipping
2015-01-05T12:56:47.759+0100    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, ns: "my_db.system.js", name: "_id_" }
2015-01-05T12:56:47.803+0100 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
assertion: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:27017 ns: my_db.$cmd query: { getlasterror: 1 }
```

If I delete system.* from the dump then mongorestore works without any errors.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Questions related to database administration and configuration belong on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). StackOverflow is a site for programming questions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is to do with the `_id_` index. Try deleting or renaming this, then doing another `mongodump` and see if that works.

I had a similar issue once and it was to do with an index. I can't remember if I deleted the index or renamed it. So it could be down to the underscores, in which case renaming it should work. Or maybe something's corrupted in the index, in which case deleting it is your only option.

Comment: I’m trying to rename or delete the system.js/_id_ index on the remote server but the index remains unchanged. I’m using Robomongo client and there are no any effect. In the log there is an error: `dropIndex failed`

Comment: Try deleting the index file from the mongodump directory and see if it imports. If it does it's definitely something to do with that index. If you can't drop the index then it may well be in use. We're getting into the specifics of your implementation here, so it will be hard to give relevant and accurate support.

Comment: Deleting the file `system.js.metadata.json` (which stores the index) solves the problem.